# Write json file from extjs ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, json, extjs

It is very simple question.

Goal : I want to update .json file with extjs ajax call.

1) Extjs code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : 'hello',                                                                                
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },                                                                                                          
jsonData: {
  "username" : "admin",
  "emailId" : "admin@sivalabs.com"
    },
success: function (response) {
     //var jsonResp = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
     //Ext.Msg.alert("Info","UserName from Server : "+jsonResp.username);
     Ext.Msg.alert('success');
   },
failure: function (response) {
  //var jsonResp = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
  //Ext.Msg.alert("Error",jsonResp.error);
  Ext.Msg.alert('fail');
   }
});
```

2) Controller class **HelloController.java** [ path: *src\com\tutorialspoint* ]

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

3) Servlet file **HelloWeb-servlet.xml** [ path: *src\main\webapp\WEB-INF* ]

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

4) web.xml [ path: *src\main\webapp\WEB-INF*]

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Sample Parent App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ParentServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ParentServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsonp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mdstech.controller.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>origin, content-type, accept, authorization</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">     
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>     
 </bean>



</web-app>
```

---

When I call that ajax call it gives me an 404 error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) /parent/HelloWeb/hello.jsp

I am very new to extjs, so please help me if you can.

Kind Regards,

Comment: More than likely the issue has nothing to do with Ext JS, given the 404. Before adding the layer of complexity of Ext JS, the first task in debugging this error will be to ensure that your desired URL works by itself. If the URL is bad, you're only going to add frustration by trying to debug a broken URL AND the layer of Ext JS. So fix your URL first, and then try again.

Comment: Yes..First debug your code and check whether your request mapping url is correct or not.Put a debug point in the url mapping function(in printHello method)  and check it.If you are able to see that the url is correct and execution is stopping at the break point ,then check do you have a folder named 'jsp' in your WEB-INF and in that folder do you have a file named hello.jsp?Check for these details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript (ExtJs) returns a 404 error for a URL, but no problems when I type it into a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180333/javascript-extjs-returns-a-404-error-for-a-url-but-no-problems-when-i-type-it)